# Null space invariance

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This question appears straightforward but I am stumped for some reason.

Suppose that $C=BAB$ Where $A$ is positive semidefinite and $B$ is symmetric. $C$ is a square matrix. I know that the nullspace of $B$ is a subset of the nullspace of $C$ but how do I show the other way around?

Are there lecture notes online which prove relationships of this sort including for the rank as well? I feel like these pop out in matrix computations book a lot and it would be nice to have a reference.

Comment: Are you sure it's true if $A$ is positive **semi**definite ? I can see that it's true if $A$ is positive definite, but if $A$ is just positive semidefinite, if $Bx \neq 0$ is in $Ker(A)$, then $Cx = 0$ so $x\in Ker(C)$, while $x\not\in Ker(B)$

Answer (score 1):

It's not true if $A$ is just positive semidefinite :

Take

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Then $A$ is positive semidefinite as $(x,y)A(x,y)^T = x^2 \geq 0$

And

$$B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

$B$ is symetric

Then

$$C=BAB = 0$$

But it's obvious that the nullspace of $B$ is not the whole space

If $A$ is positive definite :

Suppose $x$ is in the nullspace of $C$, then

$$x^TCx = 0$$

So this imply that

$$x^TBABx = 0$$

But $B$ is symmetric, so $x^TB = (Bx)^T$ so you get

$$ (Bx)^T A (Bx) = 0$$

And as $A$ is definite, $Bx = 0$,so $x$ is in the nullspace of $B$ too.